# Iterable Floats?

Tags: python, parsing, numbers, iterable, configparser

I am trying to make a game where the player is deducted .5 from a value in a ini file every time he plays. However I keep getting an error and I am not sure what to do. This is my code. Dont worry about the comments, those are for me, and I do close the while loop later. This is just a portion of the code. Btw, the code works, just not this. Thanks.

```
def rerun():
    import ConfigParser
    from ConfigParser import ConfigParser

    parser = ConfigParser()
    parser.read('Game.ini')

    PlrMny = parser.get('money_value', 'Amount')
    #config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    configFile = open("C:\Python27\Game.ini", "w")
    #config.read(configFile)
    #valueamount = config.getfloat("section","starting_value")

    print "You will be given a $10 starting amount. Each game costs $.50 to play and is
    deducted when you input the first value."
    print "\nGetting one match gives $1 and the output is multiplied by 2 for each extra 
match."
    print "\nCurrent Amount =",PlrMny,

def gamble():
    PlrMny = parser.get('money_value', 'Amount')


    import random
    import sys
    number1 = random.randint (1, 20)
    number2 = random.randint (1, 20)
    number3 = random.randint (1, 20)
    number4 = random.randint (1, 20)
    number5 = random.randint (1, 20)



    def input():
        c = 0
        print "\n\n\n\nTry guess what five numbers the computer will guess. Type '100'
        in any of the inputs to close program prematurely"    
        print "Money =",PlrMny,
        #parser.set("money_value", "Amount",10000)
        #parser.write ('Game.ini')

        while True:

            try:
                User11 = int(raw_input( "\n\nNumber 1 : "))
                parser.set('money_value','Amount',float(PlrMny) - .5)
                parser.write (configFile)
                str(PlrMny)
                if User11 < 1:
                    print "Error"
                elif User11 == 100:
                    sys.exit()
                elif User11 > 20:
                    print "Error"
                else:
                    break
            except ValueError:
                print "Error"
```

This is the Error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Gamb Game.py", line 183, in <module>
    rerun()
  File "C:\Python27\Gamb Game.py", line 182, in rerun
    gamble()
  File "C:\Python27\Gamb Game.py", line 19, in gamble
    PlrMny = parser.get('money_value', 'Amount')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ConfigParser.py", line 623, in get
    return self._interpolate(section, option, value, d)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ConfigParser.py", line 663, in _interpolate
    if value and "%(" in value:
  TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable
```

Comment: whats your ini file look like?

Comment: [money_value]
amount = 9.0

  *(on two different lines)*

Comment: @user2238780 you will get better help if you take the time to clean up your question.  You need to remove unneeded code, (ie `configFile = open("C:\Python27\Game.ini", "w")`) and it is usually helpful to remove any code that is not relevant to the question itself.  This process takes time but is a really good debugging tactic and people are more willing to help when there is less code to read

Comment: i am not quite sure, but maybe the parser is case sensitive?

Comment: @amccormack actually, that piece of code is absolutely needed otherwise I pick up a whole new error of I cannot write to file. But I understand and appreciate the tip

Comment: This thing is killing me as it is for school D:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
parser.get('money_value','Amount',True)
```

of course, you could also use:

```
PlrMny = float(PlrMny) -.5 
parser.set('money_value','Amount',str(PlrMny))
```

The problem is that parser.get is expecting a string value but is reading a float.  So the two options you have is to save the value as a string (that is what the 2nd option is doing), or to read the value using raw=True (that is what the 1st option is doing).

Comment: Omg thank you so much. As you cant tell I am a totally inept at all this. I have taken a programming class for the last semester and I am just trying to learn more. Thanks you so much. If I could +1 on the answer I would. Thanks man :DDDD

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what the problem might be in line 19. How does your config looks like and did you try

```
 parser.getfloat('money_value','Amount')
```

?

Comment: Just updated it to .getfloat and same errror and my ini can be seen above in the comments on my original post

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you create a parser in one function

```
def rerun():
    import ConfigParser
    from ConfigParser import ConfigParser

    parser = ConfigParser()
    parser.read('Game.ini')
```

and you'll use it in another.

```
def gamble():
    PlrMny = parser.get('money_value', 'Amount')
```

this ought to fail since parser is a local variable in rerun and not declared in gamble.

Comment: ahh that makes sense. Let me input that and see what I get. Well it does this weird thing where it deletes the contents of the file. This giving me a "no section" error, because it is empty

Comment: @mkind, if that were the case the error would be NameError: name 'parser' not defined.  I'm guessing we are probably not seeing the entire file, and parser may in fact be a global variable.